# Excel for Mac 2011 - Converting Address to Coordinates using Google Maps API

Tags: xml, macos, excel, google-maps-api-3, vba

I have a column of addresses that needed to be converted (geocoded) into their respective coordinates in Excel for Mac 2011.

I have a solution in the Windows version of Excel using VBA, referencing the Microsoft XML 6.0 library. and using the Google Maps API.

Unfortunately this XML library does not exist in Excel for Mac 2011.

Is there another way to use Google Maps API in Excel for Mac that is able to perform this Address conversion? I.e. is there an alternative library that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en#Limits